# Can't delete file as it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, image, process, screenshot, delete-file

I'm trying to delete a file after making a screenshot. The code is as following:

```
private static void makeSc()
    {
        DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
        string currentDT = String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd-hhmmsstt}", d);
        string scrFilename = currentDT+".jpg";
        int screenWidth = Screen.GetBounds(new Point(0, 0)).Width;
        int screenHeight = Screen.GetBounds(new Point(0, 0)).Height;
        Bitmap bmpScreenShot = new Bitmap(screenWidth, screenHeight);
        Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage((Image)bmpScreenShot);
        gfx.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, new Size(screenWidth, screenHeight));
        bmpScreenShot.Save(scrFilename, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

        //delete file
        bmpScreenShot.Dispose();
        Thread.Sleep(20);
        File.Delete(scrFilename);

    }
```

It seems that nor `Dispose()` neither the delay do it. Any thoughts?

Comment: The .Dispose is enough.  This code works for me without the error.  Do you have the file selected in Windows explorer at the time you try to delete?

Comment: Also, you should be disposing `gfx` as well.

Comment: I was actually using another method which has been using the file, and this is the place where I had to add a .Dispose method - on the object which was using the file in the called method. This part of the code was omitted from the above code because I thought it is not related to the problem, sorry for this. But after your confirmation that the above code worked I figured this out. Thanks!